# Drupal redirection

Tags: redirect, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-hooks

I am working on a project and there is a custom module in that which have the drupal redirection code in it here is the code :

```
if (empty($_GET['destination'])
&& isset($_COOKIE["abc"])
&& $_COOKIE["abc"]<>''
&& ($_POST['form_id'] != 'user_pass_reset'))
  {
   $_GET['destination'] = "xyz" ;
  }
}
```

Can anyone please explain the 3rd line of code or maybe all of it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added comments to the source. `<>` is the same as `!=`. See [PHP Comparison Opperators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

```
if (empty($_GET['destination']) //Check if $_GET['destination'] is empty.
&& isset($_COOKIE["abc"]) //Check if $_COOKIE["abc"] is not NULL.
&& $_COOKIE["abc"]<>'' //Check if $_COOKIE["abc"] does not equal an empty string.
&& ($_POST['form_id'] != 'user_pass_reset')) //Check if $_POST['form_id'] is not 'user_pass_reset'
  {
   $_GET['destination'] = "xyz" ; //Set $_GET['destination'] to "xyz"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have one more thing to ask that is there any difference between <> and != ? If they both do the same thing then there must be somewhere they should be used instead of the other like in arrays etc. Thanks.

Comment: @H_alt To the best of my knowledge, there isn't any practical difference. It's up to the developer to decide which to use. Personally, I've never seen anyone actually use `<>`.

Answer (score 0):

should be modify a little bit in second line

```
if (empty($_GET['destination']) //Check if $_GET['destination'] is empty.
&& isset($_COOKIE["abc"]) //Check if $_COOKIE["abc"] is EXISTS.
&& $_COOKIE["abc"]<>'' //Check if $_COOKIE["abc"] does not equal an empty string.
&& ($_POST['form_id'] != 'user_pass_reset')) //Check if $_POST['form_id'] is not   'user_pass_reset'
  {
   $_GET['destination'] = "xyz" ; //Set $_GET['destination'] to "xyz"
  }
}
```

Comment: `//Check if $_COOKIE["abc"] is EXISTS (IT CAN ALSO BE NULL).` This is actually inaccurate, `isset` will return `FALSE` if the value is `NULL`. `isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL` http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php